# Comparing 1842 and 1861 signatures of William Barrett?

Tags: 19th-century, england, palaeography

[image]

I have spent a long time trying to trace my gg grandfather William Barrett.

I believe he married twice first at the age of 20 in 1842 and secondly at the age of  39 in 1861. The top signature is from 1842.

I strongly feel the signature are the same person but how can I be sure?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I think you are right about the two signatures but I think there are others here that are far more skilled in comparing handwriting than me so I look forward to seeing if the answers agree.

Comment: I'm never certain on signatures either but would agree that they are the same guy. The basic ways that the W and B are formed, match, I suggest. Etc etc. The later one seems a bit shakier so he might be working harder, ill or simply standing uncomfortably.

Comment: But I would urge that you try and find other evidence to show that there is only one William Barrett in that area / era, such as censuses etc. Then again, you may have done that!

Comment: My gg grandfather was born in 1822,the son of James Barrett a carpenter,my gg grandfather was also a carpenter.I have been unable to find a second William Barrett with the same details. I would like proof the two people are one and the same hence the signature comparisons and the request for help from more experienced researchers.

Comment: My request  gets seen by a lot of people but nobody cares to give an opinion apart from the guy who welcomed me,am I unlucky or just boring?

Comment: Par for the course. Don't expect to be inundated with lots of "Metoos". What can other people say that AdrianB38 hasn't said already? The signatures look similar, alright, but is that proof the people are the same? You shouldn't expect to settle this question solely by the number of people who agree.